React Native Reanimated Responsive Issue
There is no way to create responsive animation in React Native Reanimated, I have tried thousands of way. Or is it the issue of React Native Reanimated it self?
Video Link Steps to reproduce Clone
clone this repo npm install;
For iOS run cd ios;
pod install;
npm run android or npm run iOS
Reanimated version : 3.10.0
React Native version : 0.74.0
Platforms : Android, iOS I have tried using react-native-responsive-screen to get responsive values, but still the animations are not responsive.

I dont understand what the issue is

@PhantomSpooks , please that video, you can see in big screen animation is correct in small screen they are going out of the screen. can you please please help me

could you put the git repo in a snack and post the share link? That way it'll be easier for me to take a look

Sir I have gave the repo url, please clone it and then you can reproduce it.
please sir help me
https://github.com/Vimal1464/animated-custom-drawer

If I had to guess I’d say it have something to do with using dp units

@PhantomSpooks
Sir can you please make this animation, if possible it will be really help full, I have attached a video also please please
